# Delete database entry in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am working on a project which is designed in Codeigniter. I am new to the Codeigniter framework/php and trying to learn the same. Currently I have a page which displays the table of all the results. I want to have the option of being able to delete whichever row I want to. I've added the function in model and controller and a delete icon is present in the view but I am not sure how to co-ordinate the same.

Function in Model:

```
function delete_row($job){
  $querystr = 'delete from jobs where job = \''.$job.'\'';
  $query = $this->db->query($querystr);
  $arr = $query->result_array();
  $query->free_result();
  return ;
}
```

Function in Controller:

```
public function delete(){
  $this->load->model('Job');
  $this->Job->delete_row($job);
  $this->load->view('my_view');
  return;
}
```

View:(my_view.php (snippet))

```
if($key==='job'){
echo "<input type = 'image' src = '/home/Downloads/DeleteButtonSmall.png' width='20' height ='15' name ='delete_box' >";    }
```

The view has lot of functions in it but this above line is the one which enable the delete image to all the rows visible on the display.

Please don't be harsh. Any suggestion on how to get this working. Also if the question isnt clear, feel free to post that in the comment. I will try to elaborate as much as I can.

Comment: Do you want to delete it , without the page being refreshed. ?

Comment: Yes. Though how will it differ if the page is refreshed or not. But for basic functionality, currently refreshing isnt needed.

Comment: without refresh you need to use `ajax` , with refresh, it would be more easy you do not have to use ajax then . Have you consider placing a button beside each row , which would perform the delete action .. Is this you want or something different. ?

Comment: Yes I can place a "Delete" button in front of every row.  Yes, certainly objective is to be able to delete the row, be it with Delete button or with "image" button.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not clear, but if you want to call a function in the controller (in this case delete) without refreshing you need to use ajax. and to give you more freedom use jQuery too.
here is a simple thing to give you an idea. http://jsfiddle.net/KV3WF/4/

in your controller you need to echo 1 if you deleted successfully and 0 if not.

i hope i helped in my answer if you found anything not clear please do ask.

if you want also you dont have to put onclick in html you can do it in javascript

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
           $('#category').click(function(){ //you just give an id to whatever you want to select plus you can do it by selecting a class instead id..... so you can give multiple buttons the same class("category")

                //DO the same ajax function in the jsfiddle.
           });
       //end of doc.ready   
       });
```

P.S. try to practice not to delete from the database, add a column named (hide) and update it to 1 (default is 0) when you want to delete.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand your question, but from what I understand you are trying to delete a row based on what data you clicked

on your model you could try the Active Record Pattern for delete

**Model**

```
function delete_row($job){
   $this->db->where('job', $job);
   $this->db->delete('jobs');
// DELETE from jobs WHERE job = $job
}
```

On your controller, this is where you will pass the your identifier from the view so that it can interact with the model.

**Controller**

```
function delete($id = '')
{
 $this->load->model->('Job');
 $this->Job->delete_row($id);
 redirect('to jobs view')
}
```

then on your view, you could define a link that calls your delete method in the controller and deletes a row based on the parameter you passed in the URI

say, if you pass something like this

www.example.com/controller/delete/worker

It would delete the row where job = worker

**View**

you could do it like this

```
<a href="controller/delete/worker">
<img src = '/home/Downloads/DeleteButtonSmall.png' width='20' height ='15' />
</a>
```